# Alter Firefox Back button in the PDF Reader to take you back to previous webpage not first page of the PDF

Tags: pdf, firefox, browser

PDF documents have hyperlinks that take you to the different sections of the document. After clicking the hyperlink, the Firefox back button does not take you to the previous webpage, but rather navigates to the previous section of the pdf document.  How do I disable this function, and force Firefox to take me to the previous webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the [relevant PDF.js source code](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/697b3d2f49f9b874bb2c6e628ccbe88406b4aa78/web/pdf_history.js) I don't see any way to control this: new session history entries are pushed unconditionally.